# Visual Studio 2012 Won't Run Program w/ Debugging

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

This is the error message I'm getting:

**Error while trying to run project: Unable to start program 'C:\devcode\ActiveLegacyApplications\lvLabCumFTP\bin\Debug\lvLabCumFTP_Converted.exe'.**

**Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x80040d10.**

I have cleaned/rebuilt the solution, changed CPU target from x86 to AnyCPU, and rebooted the PC. The program runs if you launch without debugging or manually from directory. I'm lost on what to do next...I've looked at about 5 other similar issues.

I did have a failed Update on Visual Studio (update 3), but it was working fine when I left work yesterday which was after the failed update....this all started when I came in this morning.

Please help!

Comment: Maybe [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/788647/error-0x80040d10-in-visual-studio-2012-when-i-try-to-execute-a-program) can be of help?

Comment: I'm trying a repair now to see if that corrects it.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases running Visual Studio as Administrator does not solve the problem. 
I experienced this with ArcMap.exe (ESRI ArcGIS 10.1).
The following made it working for me:

1. Find executable file in Windows Explorer
2. Right click on it and select "Troubleshoot compatibility"
3. Choose "Troubleshoot program" (not "Use recommended settings")
4. Check all four checkboxes and click "Next" button
5. Select Widows XP (Service Pack 3) and click Next - probably it could work with Vista also but I haven't tried this out and therefore cannot recommend
6. Click on "Test program" button - it will launch the executable
7. Close program and click on "Save changes"

If it is already saved any compatibility settings as a result of previous attempts to make the program working as intended, I would recommend to use the same scenario (use the same Troubleshooting master) for removing them prior to trying out the suggested approach.

Answer (score -1):

Run Visual Studio as admin and it will works correctely